# How to convert cubic feet into specific proportions

Tags: cubics

Forgive my ignorance, I am sure there is a better way of asking this question. Here is my problem. I want to take a certain specified volume, stated in terms of cubic feet, and structure it three-dimensionally so that it stands according to specified proportions. I want to know what the measurements of my structure will be when that is done.

Specifically, I want to take 10.089259024 cubic feet and set it up as a structure that stands in proportions of 1x1x3. What are the measurements of my structure, and how do you arrive at the solution?

Please feel free to retag appropriately as I simply want to know the answer and any help is appreciated.

Comment: $3q^3=10.08...$, then dimensions are q by q by 3q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s$ be the short side in your structure, which is then $s\times s\times 3s$.

The volume of your structure is then
$$
V = s\cdot s\cdot 3s = 3s^3
$$
So you need to solve 
$$3s^3 = 10.089\ldots \\
s= \sqrt[3]  {\frac{10.089\ldots}{3} } \approx 1.498233
$$
So your structure will be $1.498233\times 1.498233\times 4.494699$ all measurements being in feet.